# Prerequisite button in Installer project crashes Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I installed the [Installer Project Visual Studio 2015 extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/003f3135-bbca-4eb2-951d-88820065a124) and added an Installer project to an existing solution. Whenever I click on the Prerequisites button in the properties for the Installer project, VS crashes. I already rebooted the machine. Using Windows 7 64bit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a look at the official Q&A of the Extension you are using - [link here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9/view/Discussions) (You'll need to search for the question "When I show the Prerequisites dialog, why does this crash?" - probably on the oldest page of questions) - and as described, **the bug was fixed**.

Just download from the [page above](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9/view/Discussions) and install. 
*You can do a fresh install and uninstall previous version of the extension before reinstalling the newer ones but in my case that wasn't necessary.*

Answer (score 0):

Same for me on fresh install of VS2015, followed by installation of the installer project extension.

You can work around the problem with editing the installer project file (*.vdproj):

1. Open the `YOUR-SETUP-PROJECT-NAME.vdproj` file in a text editor
2. Search for `"Release"`, including the quotation marks (or any custom configuration profile name you are targeting)
3. Make sure you found s. th. similar to the structure I inserted below and that your found structure is below/within a section named `"Configurations"`
4. **Either:** completely disable the installer bootstrapper prerequisites with changing `"Enabled" = "11:TRUE"` to `"Enabled" = "11:FALSE"`
5. **Alternatively:** edit the `"Items"` list to suit your needs (you have to search for the correct entries there, of course - maybe you have an older installation of VS to produce the entries you need, or you may find matching entries via web search)

My section now looks like that:

```
"Release"
{
"DisplayName" = "8:Release"
"IsDebugOnly" = "11:FALSE"
"IsReleaseOnly" = "11:TRUE"
"OutputFilename" = "8:Release\\My Setup File Name.msi"
"PackageFilesAs" = "3:2"
"PackageFileSize" = "3:-2147483648"
"CabType" = "3:1"
"Compression" = "3:2"
"SignOutput" = "11:FALSE"
"CertificateFile" = "8:"
"PrivateKeyFile" = "8:"
"TimeStampServer" = "8:"
"InstallerBootstrapper" = "3:2"
    "BootstrapperCfg:{63ACBE69-63AA-4F98-B2B6-99F9E24495F2}"
    {
    "Enabled" = "11:FALSE"
    "PromptEnabled" = "11:TRUE"
    "PrerequisitesLocation" = "2:1"
    "Url" = "8:"
    "ComponentsUrl" = "8:"
        "Items"
        {
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I followed the path to completely disable those prerequisites which is fine for our use cases, but may be different for others of course.

Comment: could you give some more explanation on what we should do here? Instructions are quite unclear. Got the same problem and I'd love this answer to be the solution.

Comment: As explained in my answer, I worked around the problem with entirely deactivating any prerequisites check for the release compile profile. This will work for everyone, while losing the prerequisites check functionality - that is not mission critical mostly. If you do want to check for prerequisites, you have to find out and insert the corresponding entries into the "Items" brackets.

Comment: Did some research on my own. Look at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving an old project from an earlier version of Visual Studio, you should first download the Setup Installer templates from here:
[Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9)

Remove your old setup project, then create a new setup project based on the new template. Problem solved!